# Spring Security not Intercepting a particular pattern

Tags: java, xml, spring-security

In my security XML the interceptions are included as follow:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:headers>
        <security:cache-control disabled="false"/>
    </security:headers>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/login_error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            default-target-url="/home"
            always-use-default-target="false"
            />
    <security:remember-me key="uniqueAndSecret" token-validity-seconds="604800"
                          remember-me-parameter="remember-me"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="hasRole('ROLE_LOGIN')"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/business/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGE_BUSINESS')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/clover/business/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_MANAGE_BUSINESS')"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>
    <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" invalid-session-url="/login"
                                 session-authentication-error-url="/logout">
    </security:session-management>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/logout"
                     delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
</security:http>
```

With this settings, `http://localhost:8080/admin/clover/business/{businessId}?cloverAppType=kiosk`this URL is intercepted but `http://localhost:8080/admin/clover/business/{businessId}/order?cloverAppType=kiosk&appName=MainApp` this URL is not intercepted (when the user is logged out, that URL can be accessed). With usage of the `*` wild card, is that URL pattern not intercepted? What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: The pattern should be `<security:intercept-url pattern="/clover/business/**` (two asterisks for denoting path)

Comment: Yes i tried that. It works